# XPath parent node's class should not contain specific string

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I'm trying to find all `div`s whose `class` name is 'phrase' and parent node's `class` name is not 'extras'.

So in Python I'm using

```
for phrase in entry.iterfind(".//div[@class='phrase'] and ./parent::div[@class!='extras']]"):
```

to do that.

But it gives me the error:

```
SyntaxError: prefix 'parent' not found in prefix map
```

And I changed the above code to

```
for phrase in entry.iterfind(".//div[@class='phrase'] and ./..[@class!='extras']]"):
```

This time the error was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 272, in iterfind
selector = _cache[cache_key] KeyError: (".//div[@class='phrase'] and ./..[@class!='extras']]", None)
```

Part of the XML structures are as follows:

```
<div class="phrases">
    <div class="label">Phrases</div>
    <div class="phrase">
    ……

<div class="phrasal verbs">
    <div class="label">Phrases</div>
    <div class="phrase">
    ……

<div class="extras">
    <h2>test test</h2>
    <div class="phrase">
    ……
```

I'm using Python 3.7 and `xml.etree` library on Mac OS 10.14.

Comment: You have extra square bracket in predicate: `...[@class='phrase'] and ./parent...` should be `...[@class='phrase' and ./parent...`. Remove that bracket and try again

Comment: Hi @Andersson thanks for the comment. I've just removed the `]` and tried again and it still gives the `SyntaxError: prefix 'parent' not found in prefix map` error.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use *current tool*? Is it acceptable for you to use another parser like `lxml.html` for the same?

Comment: @Andersson I'm not familiar with other tools. I'll try `lxml.html` and see what happens if `xml.etree` is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might be in your current tool as it might not support some XPath syntax.

You can try [lxml.html](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) to parse the same HTML-doc:

```
from lxml import html

source = """<div class="phrases">
                <div class="label">Phrases</div>
                <div class="phrase">this</div>
            </div>

            <div class="phrasal verbs">
                <div class="label">Phrases</div>
                <div class="phrase">this</div>
            </div>

            <div class="extras">
                <h2>test test</h2>
                <div class="phrase">not this</div>
            </div>"""

dom = html.fromstring(source)
dom.xpath(".//div[@class='phrase' and ./parent::div[@class!='extras']]")
```

Output:

```
[<Element div at 0x7fb5218d5db8>, <Element div at 0x7fb521018728>] #  Two elements found
```

or

```
dom.xpath(".//div[@class='phrase' and ./parent::div[@class!='extras']]/text()")
```

Output:

```
['this', 'this']
```

Comment: This works perfectly without any problem.:) Thanks so much. @Andersson You're so awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like `"//div[@class!='extras']/div[@class='phrase']"` it should find all div's with class 'phrase' where parent class is not 'extras'

Comment: or event better to use `"//*[@class!='extras']/div[@class='phrase']"` so parent can be anything without class 'extras'

Comment: Hi @Robert Thanks for your answer. I tried `for phrase in entry.iterfind(".//div[@class!='extras']/div[@class='phrase']"):` This time it gives no errors. but it seems not to find any element through the `iterfind`.